# How to prevent the client from blocking an external resource?

Tags: jquery, api

On my website I call two APIs but AdBlock seems to blocking one of one of those.

```
//website cesare.io
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    var l = "39.069100,-11.402732"; 
    $.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/cbfb6c4b4b980e56/conditions/forecast/alert/q/"+ l +".json", function(response) {
        weather = response.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].conditions.toString();
        txt();
    });
}, "jsonp");
```

[image]

I found out users with "Disable Tracking" enabled get the error above.

[image]

How can I prevent AdBlock from blocking the callback of the ipinfo.io API?

Can I know the reason of why AdBlock disabled this API call?

Comment: You can't. The user has full control over the browser.

Comment: @Barmar So the only solution is either: 1) ask the user to disable AdBlock 2) just not call the API?

Comment: You could also call the API from a server script instead of from the browser.

Comment: Smart. Is there any way I can know the reason why AdBlock blocks certain elements in the web page?

Comment: Maybe there's something on their web site that explains it

Comment: try to use another domain/ip of service, is it possible?

Comment: to me this looks like a CORS problem, The html is on cesare.io and the javascript tries to reach http://ipinfo.io. Please google CORS

Comment: @Gavriel. You're most definitely right - so, how would you go about solving this? I thought JSONP allowed CORS, while XML didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick & dirty fix try adding this http header to http://ipinfo.io:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If you use apache, try adding this line to your .htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

If you need a proxy you can use this php script:

```
$url = "http://ipinfo.io/" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "/json";
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this have to go to my .htaccess?

Comment: what web server do you use? You can probably add it via it's configuration. If you use apache you might be able to do it in .htaccess. And if you don't mind performance you might (at least until you try if the solution works for you) make a short php script that sends that header and then the original file as body.

Comment: Thanks. embarrassingly, I don't honestly know. I just got a web hosting account from Namecheap. +1 I'm going to try your solution right now.

Comment: well http://ipinfo.io already has the access-control-allow-origin: * header :( so this is not your problem, or you use a too old browser maybe

Comment: Besodes you'll probably need to fetch "http://ipinfo.io/json" and in your code use response.loc instead of l :)

Comment: I just found out only users with "Disable Tracking enabled" in the AdBlock (see updated question) page have this issue. :(

Comment: so you might try making a small php proxy, where you fetch "http://ipinfo.io/" + $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] + "/json", and just output whatever you get, and use this proxy in your javscript (and make sure you have them on the same domain :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99313/discussion-between-cecexx-and-gavriel).

Comment: The PHP script works just great. I'd love if you could tell me what I should do next. Thanks!